# NameError: name 'encrypted_message_key' is not defined

Tags: python, file, encryption, nameerror

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
import os

password_to_encrypt = "mnwzJkdUUzUKmo8j8c3IG7MtfyIyRjkRJKxGQXX6VwQ="


def get_directories():
    global key_file, message_encrypted, message_decrypted, encrypted_message_key, decrypted_message_key
    path = 'C:/Users/ilias/PycharmProjects/virus-thing/idk'

    files = []
    # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            if '.txt' in file:
                files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

    for f in files:
        if "key.txt" in f:
            key_file = f
            print(key_file)
        elif "message_encrypted.txt" in f:
            message_encrypted = str(f)
            print(message_encrypted)
        elif "message_decrypted.txt" in f:
            message_decrypted = str(f)
            print(message_decrypted)
        elif "encrypted_message_key.txt" in f:
            encrypted_message_key = str(f)
            print(encrypted_message_key)
        elif "decrypted_message_key.txt" in f:
            decrypted_message_key = str(f)
            print(decrypted_message_key)


def generate_key_password():
    global key_file, message_encrypted, message_decrypted, encrypted_message_key, decrypted_message_key
    password_provided = password_to_encrypt
    password = password_provided.encode()
    salt = b'salt_'
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
    print(f"generate key password: {key}")
    file = open(key_file, "wb")
    file.write(key)
    file.close()


def generate_key_random():
    global key_file, message_encrypted, message_decrypted, encrypted_message_key, decrypted_message_key
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    file = open(key_file, "wb")
    file.write(key)
    file.close()


def encrypt(data):
    global key_file, message_encrypted, message_decrypted, encrypted_message_key, decrypted_message_key
    file = open(key_file, "rb")
    key = file.read()
    file.close()
    message = str(data)
    encoded = message.encode()
    f = Fernet(key)
    encrypted = f.encrypt(encoded)
    file2 = open(message_encrypted, "wb")
    file2.write(encrypted)
    file2.close()


def decrypt():
    global key_file, message_encrypted, message_decrypted, encrypted_message_key, decrypted_message_key
    file = open(message_encrypted, "rb")
    message = file.read()
    file.close()
    file = open(key_file, "rb")
    key = file.read()
    file.close()
    f = Fernet(key)
    decrypted = f.decrypt(message)
    original_message = decrypted.decode()
    file = open(message_decrypted, "w")
    file.write(original_message)
    file.close()


def encrypt_key():
    global key_file, message_encrypted, message_decrypted, encrypted_message_key, decrypted_message_key
    global encrypted_key
    file1 = open(key_file, "rb")
    random_key = file1.read()
    print(f"random_key: {random_key}")
    file1.close()
    generate_key_password()
    encrypt(random_key)
    file2 = open(message_encrypted, "rb")
    encrypted_key = file2.read()
    print(f"encrypted_key: {encrypted_key}")
    file2.close()


def encrypt_mk():
    get_directories()
    global key_file, message_encrypted, message_decrypted, encrypted_message_key, decrypted_message_key
    global encrypted_key
    generate_key_random()
    encrypt(input("data: "))
    file1 = open(message_encrypted, "rb")
    message = file1.read()
    print(f"message: {message}")
    file1.close()
    encrypt_key()
    file2 = open(encrypted_message_key, "w")
    encrypted_key = str(encrypted_key)
    file2.write(f"encrypted_message: {message}\nencrypted_key: {encrypted_key}")
    file2.close()
    clear_files()


def decrypt_mk():
    get_directories()
    global key_file, message_encrypted, message_decrypted, encrypted_message_key, decrypted_message_key
    generate_key_password()
    file1 = open(encrypted_message_key, "r")
    line1 = file1.readline()
    line2 = file1.readline()
    file1.close()
    line1 = line1.split("'")
    line2 = line2.split("'")
    encrypted_message = line1[1]
    encrypted_key = line2[1]
    file2 = open(message_encrypted, "w")
    file2.write(encrypted_key)
    file2.close()
    decrypt()
    file3 = open(message_decrypted, "r")
    read_file = file3.read()
    read_file = read_file.split("'")
    decrypted_key = read_file[1]
    file3.close()
    file4 = open(key_file, "w")
    file4.write(decrypted_key)
    file4.close()
    file5 = open(message_encrypted, "w")
    file5.write(encrypted_message)
    file5.close()
    decrypt()
    file6 = open(message_decrypted, "r")
    decrypted_message = file6.read()
    file6.close()
    file7 = open(decrypted_message_key, "w")
    file7.write(f"decrypted message: {decrypted_message}\ndecrypted key: {decrypted_key}")
    file7.close()
    clear_files()


def clear_files():
    get_directories()
    global key_file, message_encrypted, message_decrypted, encrypted_message_key, decrypted_message_key
    file1 = open(message_encrypted, "w")
    file1.write(" ")
    file1.close()
    file2 = open(message_decrypted, "w")
    file2.write(" ")
    file2.close()
    file3 = open(key_file, "w")
    file3.write(" ")
    file3.close()
```

so the output when you run encrypt_mk() is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ilias\PycharmProjects\virus-thing\main.py", line 181, in 
    encrypt_mk()
  File "C:\Users\ilias\PycharmProjects\virus-thing\main.py", line 123, in encrypt_mk
    file2 = open(encrypted_message_key, "w")

> NameError: name 'encrypted_message_key' is not defined

I can't really understand why because I clearly set it in the faction get_directories()
Does anyone know what is going on??

Comment: You define it inside one function. You use it in another function. Variables are not, by default, *global*.

Comment: presumably you don't have a file named `encrypted_message_key.txt`

Comment: @usr2564301 there's a `global` statement further up that should do the right thing

Comment: Variables defined inside a function are not available to other functions. If you need to share information between functions you can a) define the variable outside the function b) create an object with `class`, so you can use `self.` to create attributes that can be shared between functions inside that object.

Comment: @usr2564301 I made it global also at the faction it was defined in.

Comment: @JuanJavierSantosOchoa making it global in both factions isn't doing the trick?.

Comment: @SamMason pretty sure I do.

Comment: No, that's not enough. Look at this simple example: https://pastebin.com/SQqafUYd

Comment: @JuanJavierSantosOchoa just tested it you are right thank you!

Comment: @JuanJavierSantosOchoa i got another question tho why are all other variables working while i made them the same way?

Comment: @ilias In my opinion, your variable initiation is not concrete but OK because you are calling `get_directories()` at the start of  `encrypt_mk()`. As long as your code has no bugs, all the global variables would be initiated and the code will work.

Comment: Yes, @ddoGas is right, the example I provided is not exactly your case because you defined the variables with `get_directories()`. Maybe, here is the problem, in `get_directories()` you define the global variable `encrypted_message_key`, but not in all cases will assign a value. If you don't assign a value to the global then you'll get a NameErrorr when you try to use it.

Comment: @ddoGas I know it is not just trying to make it work thank you for the help!(i am programming as a hobby still learning)

Comment: @ilias I'll be happy if you accept the answer since it actually took quite a while for me to figure it out too XD

Comment: @JuanJavierSantosOchoa the problem was actually found by ddoGas the problem was that i named the files and all of them had key.txt so the assignments weren't correct still thanks for the help tho

Comment: @ddoGas hell yeah i'll accept it. Hitting my head against a wall for over 4 hours.

Comment: @ilias This is a little awkward but there is actually an accept button below the voting buttons...

Comment: @ddoGas new to the site sry for that lol.

Comment: @ilias no problem XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
for f in files:
        if "key.txt" in f:
            key_file = f
            print(key_file)
        elif "message_encrypted.txt" in f:
            message_encrypted = str(f)
            print(message_encrypted)
        elif "message_decrypted.txt" in f:
            message_decrypted = str(f)
            print(message_decrypted)
        elif "encrypted_message_key.txt" in f:
            encrypted_message_key = str(f)
            print(encrypted_message_key)
        elif "decrypted_message_key.txt" in f:
            decrypted_message_key = str(f)
            print(decrypted_message_key)
```

If you have `encrypted_message_key.txt` in f, you also have `key.txt` in f. Because `key.txt` is part of  `encrypted_message_key.txt`.
So you can never go to the `elif "encrypted_message_key.txt" in f:` branch. Same goes for `elif "decrypted_message_key.txt" in f:`.
Maybe you should check `encrypted_message_key.txt` first.